# Moving the built in identity control in MVC6 to the service layer and data layer

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I have created a simple three layer solution that contains an MVC web application project, a service layer class library project and a data layer entity framework class library project.

However the authentication/identity framework by default bypasses the service layer and data layer.  Does anyone have a simple project example where this has all been setup so only my data layer talks to the database and uses entity framework.  I am happy to create a custom user store however I am getting a bit lost trying to stitch everything together.

Help will be greatly appreciated.  Don't mind if it's a C# or VB.Net example.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here and see if it applies to your question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38673203/5233410

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving ApplicationUser and other models out of MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669833/moving-applicationuser-and-other-models-out-of-mvc-project)