# Move the Asp.net Identity 2 in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am creating layered MVC Application that contains.

- model layer:  which is not using any reference for EF
- Data Layer: which contains the infrastructure. (Repositories and unit of work ) and this layer referenced with Entity framework
- Service layer
- Web layer.

[image]

I am using Asp.net identity2. What I am doing is using `ApplicationUser` class in model layer and this leads me to reference model layer to `Entity framework` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`.
i am asking if there is a better way to do it, especially in feel that I am repeating my self while making both data layer and model layer using a reference to entity framework?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38673203/5233410

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I completely understand your question but consider not mixing your identity model with your domain objects model:

ASP.NET Identity is a presentation layer logic and you have to consider if it's a good idea detaching it from your topmost layer (Web).

I would suggest you keep your Model or Domain project with Entity framework alone and avoid mixing it with objects that are directly related to presentation.

You can take a look at this post:
https://aarcoraci.wordpress.com/2017/02/15/asp-net-mvc5-entity-framework-repository-pattern-and-unit-of-work-revisited/

Comment: Thank you . what if i need to make a navigation property between class in domain model and dbo.aspnetusers?

Comment: What I have done in the past is have a property in common. ASP.Net Identity gives you access to email (which should be always unique). You can access to this via: User.Identity.Name

All you have to do later is query your domain objects for a user with that same property.

You can create your own property if you like, just have something in common between both tables.